# Finding repeating pattern in a string

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the pattern in a string, and I am having some trouble getting the final result. I have a method that iterates over the string, if the substring is found in the input string, I add it to an array:

```
string * maxRepeat(string input) {
  string * matches = new string[22];
  for(int i = 0; i < 22; i++) matches[i] = '@';
  string s = input;
  smatch m;
  for(int i = 0; i < input.length()-1; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++){
          string foo = input.substr(j, j);
          regex e("\\b(" + foo + ")([^ ]*)"); 
          if (regex_search (input,m,e)) {
             int index = 0;
             for (auto x:m){
                 matches[index] = x;
                 index++;
          }       
        }
        i+=1;
      }
   }
 return matches;
}
```

The input string might be `249249249249`, and the smallest string I get is `249249`. How would I go about performing this operation until it is just `249`?

Comment: Do you really have to use a regex for this?

Comment: No, but I cannot figure out another way to search for patterns when the pattern is unknown ahead of time.

Comment: Just check substrings for equality, that should be enough.